# Problem with Thymeleaf dependencies of a SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf, graalvm

In my **SpringBoot 3.0** application with **Java 17** (built from *Bootify.io*), if I don't specify version for the following **Thymeleaf** dependencies, the application works correctly, and I can access **http://localhost:8080/** without problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But, if I specify the following **2.X.X** versions, I can no longer access **http://localhost:8080/**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

It fails with typicall:

*Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Dec 29 09:52:09 CET 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).*

[image]

On the other hand, I can't specify **3.X.X** dependencies, because running via **GraalVM** doesn't work. Also, if I don't specify version for Thymeleaf dependencies, execution from GraalVM fails

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3.x as parent and giving 2.x in the starter and other dependencies is the problem. The idea of parent pom is to manage all spring related versions. if you define different dependency versions in your pom xml, it will break the compatibility. Therefore you will have errors or worse(compile problems like method not found).

You can see the parent pom in the pom xml like below

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath /><!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Very rarely you may need to override versions of dependencies you can via properties [check option 2](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot)